# VS2015 html editor adding blank space after and before tag name when i use wrap and duplicate line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When i use `Wrap with` or `Duplication line`, Html editor format's like this.

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Old question, but did you find how to fix this problem?